# (Solved on Unity 5.6 beta) Unity 5.5x external dll issue on build after updade from 5.3.x

Tags: dll, monodevelop, unity-game-engine, text-to-speech, sapi

Hello Everyone and thank you for your time.
I'm facing an issue building (win x86) a specific project on Unity 5.5.0f3

Last Year using Unity 5.2.x I made some code for a project related for visually impaired persons. At that time I found a very interesting integration made by DaG_II [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/solved-speechlib-spvoiceclass-getvoices-does-crash-my-unity-executable.268011/)
He used the external DLL Interop.SpeechLib.dll to make a unity project that can interact with windows SAPI 5.x

So I took his idea, I made better samples code about how to interact with windows SAPI and I shared the code and the build (made by Unity 5.2.x) [here](http://www.finalmarco.com/2016/01/02/text-speech-unity-5/)

Now, after Unity 5.4.0 release, the code keeps run, and so the dll but trying to build unity suddenly stop whit this error:

```
*ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:371)
UnityEditor.AttributeHelper+c__Iterator31[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[UnityEditorInternal.PluginDesc]].MoveNext () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AttributeHelper.cs:277)
UnityEditor.PluginImporter+c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/PluginImporter.cs:41)
DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.CopyNativePlugins () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.cs:116)
DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.SetupStagingArea () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.cs:145)
DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/DesktopStandalonePostProcessor.cs:23)
UnityEditor.WindowsStandalone.WindowsDesktopStandalonePostProcessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WinPlayer/Extensions/Managed/WindowsDesktopStandalonePostProcessor.cs:118)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:176)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()*
```

The issue is related to the sapi dll, I awaited until unity 5.5 was released but it still not working, and I have not enought experience to figured out.

Thank you for any suggestion

Full LOG

```
Packing sprites:
SpritePacker failed to get types from Interop.SpeechLib, Version=5.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Error: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
UnityEditor.Sprites.Packer:RegenerateList() (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\Sprites\SpritePacker.cs:74)
UnityEditor.Sprites.Packer:GetSelectedPolicyId() (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\Sprites\SpritePacker.cs:102)
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck(String[], String, String, BuildTarget, BuildOptions, Boolean)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerWithDefaultSettings(Boolean, BuildOptions, Boolean) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindow.cs:464)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerWithDefaultSettings(Boolean, BuildOptions) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindow.cs:321)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons(IBuildWindowExtension, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, BuildPlatform) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindow.cs:1364)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings() (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindow.cs:1291)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI() (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindow.cs:887)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke(Object, Object[], Exception&)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222)
System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[]) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:115)
UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke(String, Object) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\HostView.cs:249)
UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke(String) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\HostView.cs:242)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI() (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\HostView.cs:76)

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs Line: 222)

- Grouping sprites using the selected SpritePackerPolicy.
- Packing 0 atlases.
- Packing completed.
Opening scene 'Temp/__Backupscenes/0.backup'
Load scene 'Temp/__Backupscenes/0.backup' time: 0.038916 ms 
Unloading 7 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
System memory in use before: 38.3 MB.
System memory in use after: 38.4 MB.
```

Comment: Actually Unity 5.6.0b5 beta I run on a Win8 VM had just successfully built the script, so I am quite confident that it will be possible build this script with unity 5.6 final release too.

Comment: I've been looking into this as well.
It states that all references from the dll need to be present.
The dll Interop.speech makes reference to mscorlib v2.0.0.0
But unity supplies mscorlib v4.0.0.0.
I wonder if we supply v2 it will work. No time to test it now though. Sorry